# Hyperledger fabric 2.0 on Kubernetes every thing work fine package install commit but invoke give me error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

```
peer chaincode invoke -o $ORDERER_URL \
            --ordererTLSHostnameOverride blockchain-orderer1 \
            --tls $CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED --cafile $ORDERER_CA \
            --channelID $CHANNEL_NAME --name ${CHAINCODE_NAME} \
            --peerAddresses $CORE_PEER_ADDRESS_ORG1 --tlsRootCertFiles $CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE_ORG1 \
            --peerAddresses $CORE_PEER_ADDRESS_ORG2 --tlsRootCertFiles $CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE_ORG2 \
            --peerAddresses $CORE_PEER_ADDRESS_ORG3 --tlsRootCertFiles $CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE_ORG3 \
            --isInit -c '{\"function\":\"initLedger\",\"Args\":[]}'
```

```
Error: endorsement failure during invoke. response: status:500 
message:"make sure the chaincode fabcar has been successfully defined on channel mychannel and try again: chaincode definition for 'fabcar' exists, but chaincode is not installed"
```

Comment: Did you instantiate the chaincode on the channel?

Comment: I am user 2.0 no instantiate the chaincode  i have commit chaincode on all endorser peer of each org

Comment: You might have installed the chaincode on peers of some organization but invoking from a different set of peers. Please verify if all the peers that you are trying to invoke from, have the chaincode installed.

Comment: The chaincode was install on right peer but the package_id of chaincode was not return that why chaincode was not commit on peer

Comment: Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

This problem is occur when you package and install chaincode successfully but when querychaincode to get package id  from log but package id variable is empty so it will not commit on peer that why this error occur